# How do I stop auth middleware in NextJS applying to server-side/pre-rendering requests?

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to require the user to be logged in to access certain routes.

I have added the following middleware, as per [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware), but am having difficulty getting it to work.

I thought the issue was down to the server-side pre-rendered page always being created while unauthenticated, but I'm no longer sure. Middleware should only run on client-side requests from a browser, right?

When I include the block marked with s, the redirect does not happen.
When it's removed, the redirect always happens, even if the user is logged in.

*Note that we're using `"next": "^12.3.3"`, and we're not ready to upgrade to next v13 yet.*

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

import * as auth from 'src/lib/auth';

const pathsNeedingAuth = [
  '/dashboard$',
  '/account/(password|reset|delete)$',
];

export default async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') { // 
    return NextResponse.next();        // 
  }                                    // 

  const pathNeedsAuth = pathsNeedingAuth.some(
    (path) => new RegExp(path).test(request.nextUrl.pathname),
  );
  if (!pathNeedsAuth) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const isAuthed = await auth.isAuthenticated();
  if (isAuthed) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const url = request.nextUrl.clone();
  url.searchParams.set('redirectUrl', url.pathname);
  url.pathname = '/account/login';
  return NextResponse.redirect(url);
}

export const config = {
  matcher: [...pathsNeedingAuth],
};
```

Any help will be appreciated! I know the structure of the code is a little odd, but that's simply from changing it while trying various things.

Comment: _"When I include the block marked with s, the redirect does not happen"_ - That's expected, Next.js middleware use the [Edge Runtime](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/edge-runtime) where `window` is not defined. How are you checking if the user is authenticated, can you show us `auth.isAuthenticated` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redirects are incompatible with [`next export`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).